# sharing variable between rails config file and javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I share variable between:

```
config/initializers/omniauth.rb
```

and

```
app/assets/javascripts/facebook.js.coffee
```

?

having to set app id in two places seems crazy clunky.

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'YOUR-APP-ID-HERE', 'YOUR-APP-SECRET-HERE'
end
```

and coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: 'YOUR-APP-ID', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/dedit/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rails 4.1**:

You will find a `secrets.yml` file in config folder. This feature was added in order to have a common storage location for the credentials.

*config/secrets.yml*

```
development:
  fb_app_id: something
  fb_app_secret: something

test:
  fb_app_id: something
  fb_app_secret: something

production:
  fb_app_id: <%= ENV["FB_APP_ID"] %>
  fb_app_secret: <%= ENV["FB_APP_SECRET"] %>
```

To access the various keys in the *secrets.yml* file you need to simply do:

```
Rails.application.secrets.fb_app_id
Rails.application.secrets.fb_app_secret
```

Give your coffee script *.erb* extension, then you will be able to do:

```
FB.init(appId: '<%= Rails.application.secrets.fb_app_id %>', cookie: true)
```

Your *omniauth.rb* will look like this:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, Rails.application.secrets.fb_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.fb_app_secret
end
```

Comment: @salivan, did you change your coffeescript extension? something like abc.coffee.erb ?

Comment: ofcourse, facebook.js.coffee.erb is this correct? and I also restarted server

Comment: I changed few things around and it started to work. Probably the cache was acting up.

Comment: weird thing, I just checked if ruby was executing, I put Time.now in place of variable and it worked. Then I put back Rails.application... and it worked :)

Comment: The important thing is it worked. And now you are following the Railsway to use credentials. :)

Comment: This works for traditional Rails apps, but not for SPAs with something like Webpack. With  Webpack and an SPA the Javascript is compiled ahead of time and served statically. Therefore, Ruby will never get the chance to interpret it as ERB and insert the constants.